# Functions are having a problem where the 'end' part is not working

Tags: lua, roblox

For some reason, I think the error messages are telling me to both take away a bracket or add one and I'm very confused. It is always either telling me that there is supposed to be something instead of the bracket or that a bracket is needed depending on how I change it. 
Here's the code:

````
local Ammo = MaxAmmo
local Reloading = false

script.Parent.Equipped:Connect(function(Mouse)
    Mouse.Icon = "rbxassetid://1008161057"
    local function Reload()
        Reloading = true
        Mouse.Icon = "rbxassetid://1008161057"
        wait(2)
        Ammo = MaxAmmo
        Reloading = false
        Mouse.Icon = "rbxassetid://1008161057"
    end
    script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
        if Ammo>0 and not Reloading then
            Ammo=Ammo-1
            if Mouse.Target.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                if Mouse.Target == ("Head") then
                    print('head')
                    Mouse.Target.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(40)
                else do
                    Mouse.Target.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(20)
                    print('body')   
                end
            end
        elseif Reloading == false then
            Reload()
        end
        print(Ammo)
    end)
    --local Input = game:GetService("UserInputService")
    --Input.InputBegan:Connect(function(Key)
        --if Key.Keycode == Enum.KeyCode.r and Reloading == false and Ammo~=MaxAmmo then
            --Reload()
        --end 
    --end)
end)```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
if Mouse.Target == ("Head") then
  print('head')
  Mouse.Target.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(40)
else do
  Mouse.Target.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(20)
  print('body')   
end
```

Either add an `end` to that `do` or remove it.

To fix such errors count all keywords that require an end and all ends and see if you get the same number. There are text editors that help you with that

Answer (score 0):

You should use an IDE like ZeroBraneStudio, or IntelliJ Community (with EmmyLua)

First issue:

```lua
if Mouse.Target.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                if Mouse.Target == ("Head") then
                    print('head')
                    Mouse.Target.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(40)
                else do
                    Mouse.Target.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(20)
                    print('body')   
                end
            end
```

You should remove `do` from `else do`

Second issue:

You'll be getting "unexpected )" from here:

```
            print(Ammo)
        end)
```

This is because you're missing an end from `if Ammo > 0 and not Reloading then`

The resultant code should look like this:

```lua
local Ammo = MaxAmmo
local Reloading = false

script.Parent.Equipped:Connect(function(Mouse)
    Mouse.Icon = "rbxassetid://1008161057"
    local function Reload()
        Reloading = true
        Mouse.Icon = "rbxassetid://1008161057"
        wait(2)
        Ammo = MaxAmmo
        Reloading = false
        Mouse.Icon = "rbxassetid://1008161057"
    end
    script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
        if Ammo > 0 and not Reloading then
            Ammo = Ammo - 1
            if Mouse.Target.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                if Mouse.Target == ("Head") then
                    print('head')
                    Mouse.Target.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(40)
                else
                    Mouse.Target.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(20)
                    print('body')
                end
            elseif Reloading == false then
                Reload()
            end
            print(Ammo)
        end
    end)
    --local Input = game:GetService("UserInputService")
    --Input.InputBegan:Connect(function(Key)
    --if Key.Keycode == Enum.KeyCode.r and Reloading == false and Ammo~=MaxAmmo then
    --Reload()
    --end
    --end)
end)
```

Comment: that's a pretty long post for pointing out a superfluous `do`

Comment: There is no second issue. The error message is a red herring, caused by the actual issue.